# Undeclared property validation in compile time for Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I noticed that a Parent Component can pass undeclared properties to Child Components.

I have a `base-button` with the following props:

```js
const properties = {
  'label': {
    'type': String,
    'required': false
  },
  'icon': {
    'type': String,
    'required': false
  },
  'variant': {
    'type': String as PropType<BaseButtonVariant>,
    'default': 'primary',
    'required': false,
    'validator': validateVariant
  }
};
```

When a Parent Component use `base-button` can send any property:

```js
<div>
  <base-button
    v-for="button in visibleButtons"
    :key="button.buttons"
    :disabled="isDisabled(button.buttons)"
    :label="button.label"
    :variant="button.variant"
    @click="onClick(button.response)"
  />
</div>
```

In this case `disabled` and the `@click` event are not being declared as a property in my `base-button`.

There are any way to trigger an error in compile time ?

I tried the [Disabled Attribute Inheritance](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-attrs.html#disabling-attribute-inheritance), but it does not work.

Comment: The click event isn't a property and disabled is a known HTML attribute and Vue usually applies these to a wrapping html element in the child component unless you are using multiple root elements.

Comment: @Thomas thank you for you comment, I understand what you are saying. However, when for example I add: `:other-property="false"`, and is not explicit declared in the Vue component, it is still passing to my child component. I'm would like to know how to prevent this in Vue.